# How to separate erroneously combined words in OCRed text?

Tags: awk, sed, ocr, text-processing

I have the text of a long document that was OCRed by someone else that contains a lot of instances where the spacing wasn't recognized properly and two words are run together (ex: divisionbetween, hasalready, everyoneelse). Is there a relatively quick way using awk, sed, or the like to find strings that are not words and check if they can separated into legitimate words?

Or is there some other quick way to fix them? For instance, I notice that Chrome is able to flag the combined words as misspellings and when you right click, the suggested correction is pretty much always the one I want, but I don't know a quick way to just auto-fix them all (and there are thousands).

Thanks!

Comment: you need better tools, split the strings not in dictionary at various positions and compare for maximum likelihood of the split.  You may need a context of surrounding text to make better decisions.  Infamous example:  "expertsexchange"

Comment: From what I can tell, the vast majority of the errors of this kind in the document appear to be combinations of only two words. Also, for what it's worth, the Chrome spell checker offers only one correction suggestion for ``expertsexchange`` and it's ``experts exchange``. And it doesn't offer to correct therapist. Ultimately, I'm not looking for a perfect solution, but for a solution that will clean up the thousands of obvious OCR errors. Thanks!

Comment: @EdMorton, you should skip dictionary words and assume they are not combined.  MattV "expert sex change" is another alternative interpretation.  Chrome has Google AI behind it, your script won't.

Comment: @karakfa, Even vim's built-in spell checker offers ``experts exchange`` as the first suggestion to correct ``expertsexchange`` (and doesn't flag therapist, obviously). I had hoped I could just use a vim macro to accept the first spelling suggestion, but the macro I tried recording seems to pause at the point where I recorded choosing the first offered suggestion. Oh well, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt you're likely to create errors while you're fixing others trying to do this with command line tools but if you have a dictionary of words then you could do something like this using GNU awk for `patsplit()` and multi-char `RS` in case any of your files have DOS line endings:

```
$ cat words
bar
disco
discontent
exchange
experts
foo
is
now
of
tent
winter

$ cat file
now is the freezing winter
of ExPeRtSeXcHaNgE discontent
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = "\r?\n"
    minSubLgth = 2
    minWordLgth = minSubLgth * 2
}
NR==FNR {
    realWords[tolower($0)]
    next
}
{
    n = patsplit($0,words,"[[:alpha:]]{"minWordLgth",}+",seps)
    printf "%s", seps[0]
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        word = words[i]
        lcword = tolower(word)
        if ( !(lcword in realWords) ) {
            found = 0
            for (j=length(lcword)-minSubLgth; j>=minSubLgth; j--) {
                head = substr(lcword,1,j)
                tail = substr(lcword,j+1)
                if ( (head in realWords) && (tail in realWords) ) {
                    found = 1
                    break
                }
            }
            word = (found ? "[[[" substr(word,1,j) " " substr(word,j+1) "]]]" : "<<<" word ">>>")
        }
        printf "%s%s", word, seps[i]
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk words file
now is the <<<freezing>>> winter
of [[[ExPeRtS eXcHaNgE]]] discontent
```

to identify the case-insensitive alphabetic strings that aren't in the words list and then iteratively create pairs of substrings from each of those and see if those substrings are in "realWords[]". It'd be somewhat slow and approximate and only work for when 2 words are combined, not 3 or more but maybe it'll be good enough. Think about the algorithm as it may or may not be the best way to split the substrings (I didn't give it much thought), tweak not to look up words of less than some number of letters (I used 4 above), not split into substrings of less than some other number of letters (I used 2 above), and you may or may not really want to highlight words that don't appear in `realWords[]` but you can't split into substrings that are present either (`freezing` above).

FWIW I downloaded the list of words from https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt (you might want to google for a better list as this one seems to contain some non-words like `wasn` and `ll`) and using a version of the text in your question with some additional spaces removed you can see some of the things this can catch, some it can't resolve, and some it gets wrong:

```
$ cat file
I have the textof a long document that was OCRed by someoneelse that contains
a lot ofinstances where the spacingwasn't recognized properly and two words
are run together (ex: divisionbetween, hasalready, everyoneelse). Is there a
relatively quickway using awk, sed, or the like tofind strings that are not
words andcheck if they can separatedintolegitimate words?

Or is there someother quick way to fix them? Forinstance, Inotice that
Chrome is able toflag the combined words asmisspellings and when you right
click, thesuggested correction is pretty much always the oneIwant, but I
don't know a quickway to just auto-fix themall(and there are thousands).

$ awk -f tst.awk words_alpha.txt file
I have the [[[text of]]] a long document that was [[[OC Red]]] by [[[someone else]]] that contains
a lot [[[of instances]]] where the [[[spacing wasn]]]'t recognized properly and two words
are run together (ex: [[[division between]]], [[[has already]]], [[[everyone else]]]). Is there a
relatively [[[quick way]]] using awk, sed, or the like [[[to find]]] strings that are not
words [[[and check]]] if they can <<<separatedintolegitimate>>> words?

Or is there [[[some other]]] quick way to fix them? [[[For instance]]], [[[Ino tice]]] that
Chrome is able [[[to flag]]] the combined words [[[as misspellings]]] and when you right
click, [[[the suggested]]] correction is pretty much always the <<<oneIwant>>>, but I
don't know a [[[quick way]]] to just auto-fix [[[thema ll]]](and there are thousands).
```

FWIW that took about half a second to run on cygwin on my [underpowered] laptop.